# Apache isn't running my PHP index script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

If I decide to place this in my [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess) file:

```
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The site runs fine. I then decided to `mv index.php subdir/index.php`, so I change the last line to the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And all I see is an Apache directory listing. What am I doing wrong? This probably a very simple solution, but my resources haven't turned up anything.

What bothers me is that this *should* work. It is intuitive and natural to think that all that is needed is to change the file location of `index.php`.

### Edit

I have tried `RewriteBase`, and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdir/index.php`. Neither has worked.

Comment: This is probably a sub-query artefact.  Try specifying `Options -MultiViews` and also check that you *don't* have a `subdir/.htaccess` as this will be parsed on internal redirect.

Comment: Added `Options -MultiViews`, to no avail. Used `ls -a` to verify no `.htaccess` file in `subdir/`.

Comment: You're also doing an autoindex.  Try doing a `DirectoryIndex index.php` to disable this and BTW `IndexIgnore` takes a filename, not a fullpath so `*/*` isn't going to work :-)

Comment: I swapped the `IndexIgnore` with `DirectoryIndex index.php`, and now I see a full directory listing of the site.

Comment: "Apache directory listing" vs "full directory listing".  Can you explain?  I was also meaning that you need `IndexIgnore *`.

Comment: As in just the title, vs. seeing the files. I added `IndexIgnore *`, and now I don't see the file listing, but see the title of the directory listing (ex. "Index of dir").

Comment: On that note, can someone explain the down vote on all the answers?

Comment: Didn't do any down-voting myself, but I do think that it fairly valid to regard 3 answers which are pretty much identical and the same as something that the OP's tried and not work as "not useful"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried enabling rewrite logging? Try adding this to your vhost:

```
RewriteLogLevel 3
RewriteLog "/usr/local/var/apache/logs/rewrite.log"
```

The rule you posted seems to work just fine for me...

**Edit:**

Ok I was able to replicate the issue on my Mac and figured out that this is what you need:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is, when you just go to `http://localhost/` `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` doesn't have a value. There might be a way to combine these rules into one, but I haven't figured it out yet.

**Edit 2:**

I just tried this and it also worked:

```
DirectoryIndex subdir/index.php

RewriteEngine On   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

However, it doesn't have anything for the value of the page_request `$_GET` variable, so you'd have to handle that case in your code.

This works because you're telling Apache to look in the subdirectory for the index page instead of the current directory.

Comment: As I mentioned, it has go to in your vhost. :)

Comment: As soon as I typed that I realized it, one sec

Comment: Ok, here's the rewrite log. The root dir is `~/Documents/root/e119`, and the subfolder is `~/Documents/root/e119/e119/`. http://cl.ly/1p1Q0E2m2d0l1I0L0v0P

Comment: To clarify, my goal is to redirect whatever comes after `http://localhost/e119/` to `root/e119/e119/index.php?page_request=whatever`.

Comment: Interesting. What URL are you requesting? I'm seeing a request for index.html which makes me think you're requesting a folder with no filename and its setup to look for index.html first? Also, what version of Apache?

Comment: I'm requesting `http://localhost/e119/`. Apache/2.2.21 (Unix). I'm on a Mac by the way.

Comment: Yeah that `index.html` is weird, so here's what happens when I put `DirectoryIndex index.php` in the .htaccess: http://cl.ly/1S1C0k351N2R0o0b0m0d. (same problem with the directory listing occurs though)

Comment: Have you tried adding `RewriteRule /`? Also, what happens if you rename the subdir to something other than e119? Does it make any difference? I'm wondering if something strange is happening with figuring out where the index.php file is located..

Comment: You mean RewriteBase? yes. Same things happen if I rename the subdir.

Comment: Yes, I meant RewriteBase... oops.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the slash..

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]

Comment: Nope, sorry. `RewriteBase` doesn't work either for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/subdir/index.php 
RewriteRule (.*) /subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: From this I get an Internal Server Error. The apache logs say "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: Yes, this no longer causes an error... but it just loads the Apache directory listing. Did you run test the code, or was it a guess? Just so I know if there is something different on my server.

Comment: Which directory is it listing?

Comment: It's just an `<h1>` tag with **Index of root_dir/** in it

Answer (score -1):

Use this:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subdir/index.php?page_request=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: As I said in replying to the other answer, I tried RewriteBase and unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: Does anything echo to your access_log, or more importantly, error_log?

Comment: Nope, nothing to either. It runs without errors, and just displays the Apache directory.